# How to call parent form content editor javascript on opening and closing modal popup form?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a javascript function in allitem view page's content editor.
I want to call it after "add new item" modal popup form open and close.

Thank for help.

Comment: Check this once https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fa7d56b5-278b-4e16-9400-497d8c25f03b/call-function-when-spuimodaldialogshowmodaldialog-is-opening-or-after-open?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious it may help you

Comment: It's doesn't work for me. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage(url, callback, width, height) Method`.

Refer below example:

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage('https://abcabc.sharepoint.com/sites/RohitW/Lists/TestList/NewForm.aspx', callback, 500, 500);

function callback(){
      // here you can write your callback javascript code
}
```

Reference :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410825(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Can I inject it to list default new form popup event?

Comment: You can use jquery directly on the popup form to inject and enable this.